# Excel 2010 Convert Text (Date + Time) to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched and attempted numerous different solutions with none of them working for me. Maybe I am missing something or doing something wrong, but here is my situation.

I have a column with a cell **I1** being the title. I have a text string in this format `(7/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM)`. I need to convert this to just the date in `MM,DD,YYYY` format. The data grows and shrinks for defining which cells to convert gets messy.

Please help. I am hitting a brick wall with this one.

```
Invoice Date
7/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
6/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
5/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
4/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
3/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
2/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
1/1/2013 12:00:00:000000 AM
12/15/2012 12:00:00:000000 AM
10/29/2012 12:00:00:000000 AM
10/16/2012 12:00:00:000000 AM
8/29/2012 12:00:00:000000 AM
```

This is the column data I am trying to convert in column I.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula,

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))
```

[image]

If you need vba solution, use this formula in vba to replace contents of the source data.

Comment: I would recommend wrapping that formula with a `DATEVALUE(...)` so that the result is an actual date.  Having cells containing text that **looks** like a date, but isn't actually a date, is a guaranteed source of future problems.  (The cell should then be formatted using whatever date format is desired, rather than "General" format.)